# Why are items automatically purchased for me?

Tags: dota-2

In every game items are automatically purchased for me throughout the game without me adding them to the quick buy area.

The behavior is as follows:

1. Game starts.
2. Items are automatically bought.  The items include the Donkey
   courier thing, a town portal, some tree eating potions, and some
   kind of dust that I can't remember the name of.
3. As the game progresses, additional items are purchased like the
   invisibility pendant and more potions.

It completely destroys the ability to buy any meaningful items and puts me at a serious disadvantage.  I've gone through the settings and don't see any auto-buy new player setting.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: can you add more details as to what you are seeing?  Are you sure they are in your inventory (6 squares on bottom right) rather than suggested items in the list?  Also, are you losing gold?

Comment: Other moba games have had a beginner mode that buys items for you, not sure for DOTA2 but worth checking

Comment: @Domocus DOTA2 currently has a suggested items list, but I haven't seen any cases where it buys an item for you yet.

Comment: I've updated the post with more details.

Comment: totally weird, sounds like you are being controlled by a bot or something

Comment: @yx.  Yes they show up in my inventory.  No, they are not in the quick buy.  Yes I lose gold.  To start the game I normally have between 100-200 after the auto buying occurs.

Comment: @drneel When you first booted up Dota 2, did you select that you were a beginner? Is this happening in practice mode, or is it during ranked games?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the setting, but I'm not sure how it got turned on as I chose expert or whatever the highest level setting was.  Switched that and then everything got better.

[image: Problem Setting]

Comment: Weird. That must be a new feature they added, since I don't remember seeing that. Glad you found it though.

Comment: This was on by default for me when I started playing about a month ago; don't think it's new.

Comment: My first game that I played I didn't have any problem, but then after they released an update or something the other night it started happening.

Comment: it is an option you can turn on and off in options